# Install cannot modify hard disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount

I am running into an issue with installing Ubuntu from a multi-boot thumbdrive.

I CAN boot the OS, but install fails due to unable to umount /isodevice ("target is busy" error)
Issuing the command:

```
  sudo umount -f /isodevice
```

also results in "target is busy" message.

The problem appears to be that the .iso file that is mounted at /isodevice is 
 NOT from the thumbdrive, but from the same named .iso on one of the hard drive partitions.
There appears to be some logic that tells the system to mount this .iso instead of the 
one on the thumbdrive.

The grub configuration that I am booting with looks like this:

```
   menuentry "(u) Ubuntu  Live/Install." --hotkey=u --class ubuntu {
      set iso="$imagedir/$ubuntu"
      search --set -f $iso
      loopback loop $iso
      linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename=$iso file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper noeject toram quiet splash
      initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
   }
```

where "imagedir" is the device & directory where the image is kept.
 and "$ubuntu" is the .iso image name.

Is there any way to force the kernel to load the .iso from the thumbdrive instead of the hard drive?
I don't want to have to worry about existing .iso files on hard disks when using this thumbdrive 
for installation...

Thanx

Richard Rosa

Comment: I loopmount install all the time. But have to manually change some mounts.  But only install to sdb from ISO on sda, or to sda from ISO on sdb. I also use toram parameter, but offer by installer to unmount partition never seems to work. Ubuntu Installer uses wrong bootloader location for USB/sdb UEFI installs 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1173457
Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 & 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1229488

Comment: Also if using toram, then unmount isodevice.  # Required as /isodevice usually mounts to a partition and installer does not correctly unmount
`sudo umount -lrf /isodevice`

Comment: @oldfred - Thanx for the info. The parms in the 'umount' removed the mounted partition, and allowed installation. Not sure WHY this is mounted (or why it selects the ISO on the HD), as it does not appear to be needed for install. Not a fix, but at least this is a work-around. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Also if using toram parameter, then unmount isodevice. # Required as /isodevice usually mounts to a partition and installer does not correctly unmount, even though it may ask.

```
sudo umount -lrf /isodevice
```

Also if you want grub to install to any device other than sda or first NVMe device you can manually change during install process to correct it.

Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install, see #23 & #26, but note other comments.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379